# Get products to display based on custom attribute

Tags: php, products, custom-attributes

I have an custom attribute on each product called 'sidebar' which is a yes/no option. All the products that are set to 'yes' I would like to appear inside a div I have in 3columns.phtml. All I want to display is:

- title
- image (hyperlinked)
- price

I tried the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value just to get a basic idea of the query but this didn't work for me. I tried:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('sidebar');  
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('orig_price');    


$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('sidebar'=>'orig_price','eq'=>'yes'),  
));

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    //var_dump($product);
    var_dump($product->getData());
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using attribute **option id** rather than **option label value**.

Example:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addUrlRewrite()
    ->addPriceData()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sidebar', array('eq' => 1));

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($product->getData());
}
```

Since you mentioned that `sidebar` is a drop down attribute I'm assuming `No => 0 and Yes => 1`

Answer (score 0):

use also this

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($product->toArray())
}
```

exit;

now check your needed attribute//